# Show that $||X||$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed numbers and the following norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$ ||x|| = \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}} \qquad x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$
Prove that it is, in fact, a norm.

Taking the rules of a norm, I get the following:

1. $||x||\geq0$: since we take $x_1^2$ and $x_2^2$, it will never be negative.
2. $||x||=0 \iff x=0$: same applies here. It is only $0$ if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $0$.
3. $||\lambda x||=|\lambda|||x||$: $||\lambda x||=\lambda \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}}=\sqrt{ \frac{\lambda^2x_1^2}{a^2}+ \frac{\lambda^2x_2^2}{b^2}}=\sqrt{\lambda^2 (\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2})}=|\lambda|\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}}=|\lambda| ||x||$
4. $||x+y||\leq||x||+||y||:$The triangle inequality is the point where I got stuck. Not sure if $||x+y||= \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}+\frac{y_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{b^2}}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{y_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{b^2}}$.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Actually the scaling part should be 
$$
||\lambda x||=\sqrt{\frac{(\lambda x_1)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(\lambda x_2)^2}{b^2}}=\sqrt{\lambda^2\left(\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}\right)}=|\lambda|\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}}=|\lambda| ||x||
$$

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $x+y=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$ so we have that $$||x+y||=\sqrt{\frac{(x_1+y_1)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x_2+y_2)^2}{b^2}}$$ is the correct first step. You then need to manipulate it to show that it is greater than $$||x||+||y||=\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{y_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{b^2}}$$

Comment: So writing $$||x+y||=\sqrt{\frac{(x_1+y_1)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x_2+y_2)^2}{b^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}+\frac{y_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{b^2}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{y_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{b^2}}=||x||+||y||$$ would prove it, am I correct?

Comment: No, because your second equality is wrong. $(x_1+y_1)^2=x_1^2+2x_1y_1+y_1^2$

Comment: Yes, I slipped over that. But I still don't see how it will lead to the inequality.